# What does "episodic training" mean?

Tags: training, terminology, meta-learning

I'm reading the book [Hands-On Meta Learning with Python](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/hands-meta-learning-python), and in Prototypical networks said:

> So, we use episodic training—for each episode, we randomly sample a
> few data points from each class in our dataset and we call that a
> support set and train the network using only the support set, instead
> of the whole dataset.

I think, but I'm not sure, I have understood what "episodic training" is, but what is the meaning of "episodic" or "episode" here?

I'm sorry, I'm not English and I can't guess what it is meaning searching in a dictionary. I know what an episode is, but I don't know what an episode, in this context of training, means.

Answer (score 1):

It consists of organizing training in a series of learning problems, each relying on small "support" and "query" sets to mimic the few-shot circumstances encountered during evaluation.(an episode is a single task)